# How to use page method to bind control to differnet data sources?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

If I have radiobuttonlist like this:

```
 <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbtn_PeriodTypeName" runat="server" DataTextField="PeriodTypeName" DataValueField="PeriodTypeId" AutoPostBack="true" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

And according to the user selection, I have to bind my dropdownlist from database.

```
<telerik:RadDropDownList ID="ddl_PeriodType" runat="server">

</telerik:RadDropDownList>
```

How to do something like that using Ajax page method?

EX:

My radio button list:

- 1
- 2
- 3

If the user select 2 the dropdownlist should be like this:

- W1
- W2
- W3

Comment: If you want to reload the page every time on radio button select. Use `SelectedIndexChanged` event of the radio button and rebind the dropdown based on selected index. If you do not want to reload the page, then use `AJAX` to refresh dropdown list on client side using webapi or webmethod.

Answer (score 3):

Bind the data for all the drop downs in the initial load of the page if

1. the number of options in each of the dropdowns is not too much
2. the data source of the dropdowns doesn't change based on the radio button selected

And, toggle the visibility of the drop downs in the client side based on the radio button selected in the client side itself..

Answer (score 1):

Write jquery ajax method to call your server side function in that bind your values to your control by creating new object of your class (as it will be the static method)

Answer (score 0):

- bind first combo at page load
- on selectionchanged client side event trigger an ajax call for ajax
  method
- this ajax method will get the list items of next combo based on
  selected Id of 1st